# Align line annotation label and label annotation

Tags: chart.js

I'm using `chartjs-plugin-annotation` version 2.1.1 to draw a line and a couple of labels on a chart.

With `position: 'end'` the label is aligned to the right.

```
const l1 = {
      type: 'line',
      label: {
        display: true,
        content: 'line',
        position: 'end',

      },
      scaleID: 'y',
      value: 62,
    };
```

However, I am not able to draw a label annotation vertically-aligned (to the right) with the label of the line.

I have tried several

```
const l2 = {
      type: 'label',
      yValue: 0,
      position: 'end',
   // position { x: 'end' },
      content: 'label'     
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 2):

The position of the label can be used to define where the label must be located, compared to the point defined by `xValue` and `yValue` option.

Probably the best way is to use line annotations, with the same config, apart for value.

```
const l2 = {
  type: 'line',
  label: {
    display: true,
    content: 'line',
    position: 'end',
  },
  borderWidth: 0, // no line
  scaleID: 'y',
  value: 0
};
```

Or in you label annotation, you could set `xValue` and `xAdjust` as following:

```
const l2 = {
  type: 'label',
  yValue: 0,
  xValue: (context) => context.chart.scales.x.max,
  position: 'end',
  content: 'label',
  color: 'white',
  xAdjust: (context) => -context.chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.l1.label.padding,
  backgroundColor: 'black'
}
```